# How to lessen geometry of an object during animation

Tags: python, node-editor, bezier-curves, animation-nodes, geometry

I'm  using Blender 2.8 to animate the growth of a curve that is beveled using python and Animation Nodes 2.1.4 (running Ubuntu 18.04 64bit) The animation generates about 2.6+ million vertices and faces when the animation finally reaches the end.

At each frame the vertices and faces are increased due to its "growth".  Is there a way to decimate or control the amount of vertices / faces in Animation Nodes or does anyone know of another way to prevent the generation of so many vertices / faces or to lessen them during the animation process?

Here's the Animation Nodes.
[image: An Node]

Python Code: used to generate the data:

```
import math
import numpy as np


def lorenz(x, y, z, s=10, r=28, b=2.667):

    x_dot = s*(y - x)
    y_dot = r*x - y - x*z
    z_dot = x*y - b*z
    return x_dot, y_dot, z_dot


dt = 0.008
#num_steps = 150

# Need one more for the initial values
xlist = np.empty(num_steps + 1)
ylist = np.empty(num_steps + 1)
zlist = np.empty(num_steps + 1)

# Set initial values
xlist[0], ylist[0], zlist[0] = (0., 1., 1.05)

# Step through "time", calculating the partial derivatives at the current point
# and using them to estimate the next point
for i in range(num_steps):
    x_dot, y_dot, z_dot = lorenz(xlist[i], ylist[i], zlist[i])
    xlist[i + 1] = xlist[i] + (x_dot * dt)
    ylist[i + 1] = ylist[i] + (y_dot * dt)
    zlist[i + 1] = zlist[i] + (z_dot * dt)
```

Example of animation of the [Lorenz Attractor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorenz_system) being generated:

[image: Animation]

I've also attached the blend file.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the *Slice List* node to reduce the number of spline points. To do so, disable the *Start* and *End* options of the node and enable the *Step* option. The higher the step is, the less spline points you will get.

[image: Node Tree]

Comment: Wow Thanks!!!  That gives me the ability to drastically cut my vertices / faces down and the quality can be varied.  Thanks so much!!! From 2.6 million to a couple 100 thousands...So many equations to animate so little time :-)